# The CRAN check results shows that for "r-release-windows-ix86+x86_64" it is an ERROR

Tags: r, package, release, cran

got an question for R release.

I have upload R package to CRAN.

However, after CRAN Package Check Results finish, the result shows as below:

Is there a way to check whether this problem is fix or not without release a 0.2.1 package to CRAN? (I tried `R-hub` builder but it does nor find this error)

[image]

It's wired, as only "r-release-windows-ix86+x86_64: ERROR".
And my windows system release ok for the package, that makes me a bit hard to figure out the problem.
Then I checked the error detailed document, it shows like this

Anyone knows what may cause the problem?

[image]

Comment: We can't look at it unless you give us the URL.

Comment: Package `dplyr` includes a shared library, .dll in WIndows. R's package installation routine is not finding it. Try to reinstall `dplyr` and see if it solves the problem. Also, what is your `.libPaths()`? How is it set?

Comment: Thank you for helping Rui. I am trying to, is there a way to check whether this problem is fix or not without release a 0.2.1 package to CRAN? (I tried ```R-hub builder``` but it does nor find this error) Also, I am not sure, if ```.libPaths()``` the path I was used when creating R file or ...?

Comment: You can check if a package can be submitted to CRAN from the command line with `R CMD check --as-cran pkgname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system automatically pass that state. Looks good now.

I still not sure why, but CRAN Package Check Results for Packag shows that the `T_install` & `T_check` increases from "3", "6" to "30", "127" respectively.

So, maybe because it just requires more time and choices to do the check? So that the state may change from "error" to "ok"

Comment: Likely there was a transient problem at CRAN causing `dplyr` to be improperly installed.  Maybe it was in the middle of installing a `dplyr` update when it checked your package.